# How to quote string with lots of " and '?

Tags: shell

I need to run a function like this:

```
process_del_netdevice()
{
    curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080${1}monitor" --header \
        "Content-Type: application/json" --header \
        "x-auth-token: $AUTH_TOKEN" -d '{"cmd": "device_del netdev-'$2'"}'

    curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080${1}monitor" --header \
        "Content-Type: application/json" --header \
        "x-auth-token: $AUTH_TOKEN" -d '{"cmd": "netdev_del '$2'"}'

    curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080${1}monitor" --header \
        "Content-Type: application/json" --header \
        "x-auth-token: $AUTH_TOKEN" -d '{"cmd": "chardev-remove char-'$2'"}'
}
```

But I need to output the command I have run, so I want to codes like this:

```
process_del_netdevice()
{
    res="curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080${1}monitor" --header \
        "Content-Type: application/json" --header \
        "x-auth-token: $AUTH_TOKEN" -d '{"cmd": "device_del netdev-'$2'"}'"

    echo $res
}
```

But remind me errors, so how to echo this command I run? Thank you~

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is directly relevant.

Comment: BTW, your usage doesn't safely quote values of `$2` that can't be substituted directly into a JSON string. Consider using `jq` to generate the argument in question.

Comment: (BTW -- what's the context? Generally, the best answer on questions about handling shell commands as strings rather than arrays is "don't"; providing enough details that we understand why that answer doesn't apply to you might also guide a response more applicable and appropriate to your use case -- for instance, many answers that work in bash to generate code for consumption *by bash* aren't guaranteed to generate code that can be executed by other, non-bash, POSIX shells in the presence of nonprintable characters).

Answer (score 1):

This could be quoted correctly but that would get very unreadable. I would suggest a second function that does the printing and executing.

```
execute_and_print() {
  "$@"
  printf '%q ' "$@"
  printf '\n'
}
```

and in your code:

```
    process_del_netdevice()
    {
    execute_and_print curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080${1}monitor" --header \
        "Content-Type: application/json" --header \
        "x-auth-token: $AUTH_TOKEN" -d '{"cmd": "device_del netdev-'$2'"}'

    execute_and_print curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080${1}monitor" --header \
        "Content-Type: application/json" --header \
        "x-auth-token: $AUTH_TOKEN" -d '{"cmd": "netdev_del '$2'"}'

    execute_and_print curl "http://127.0.0.1:8080${1}monitor" --header \
        "Content-Type: application/json" --header \
        "x-auth-token: $AUTH_TOKEN" -d '{"cmd": "chardev-remove char-'$2'"}'
}
```

Correct quoting can also achieved by:

```
for param in "$@"; do
  printf "'%s' " "$(printf '%s' "$param" | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g")"
done
printf '\n'
```

Comment: If you want `eval`-safe quoting, that needs to be: `printf '%q ' "$@"`. With `'%s '`, you can't tell the difference between `echo "hello world"` and `echo "hello" "world"`.

Comment: **However**, that doesn't buy you anything that the shell doesn't give you for free with `set -x`, if the purpose is logging.

Comment: (that said -- AFAICT, the user is *only* trying to print a command, and not to immediately execute it at all. If that's really true, then fix the `%s`/`%q` issue, remove or conditionalize the `"$@"`, and perhaps document that the resulting string needs to be used in `eval` or an equivalent context to execute it, and this will be the best answer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the question was not taged with bash so I avoided `%q` and added a sed suggestion for readability. And "need to output the command I have run" is explicitly mentioning the execution. Although i mixed up the order.

Comment: The thing is, **if you don't use `%q` or some equivalent, the output is simply wrong**. It *doesn't* reflect quoting properly in output.

Comment: ...not to say that there aren't alternatives available if you have a POSIX shell. I've been known to use the Python `pipes.quote()` (or, in Python 3, `shlex.quote()`) tools in a helper for the purpose.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy also I hit submit to fast. (Did not update his code with the execute_and_print call). Check the updated answer, `"$@"` should be totally okay to execute it instead of `eval`.

Comment: Observe the output of `execute_and_print printf '%s\n' "hello world"`: It emits as output `printf %s\n hello world`.  When *that* is `eval`ed, its output is `hellonworldn`.

Comment: By contrast, consider `print_quoted() { python -c 'import sys, pipes; print(" ".join(pipes.quote(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]))' "$@"; }`; when *that's* run as `print_quoted printf '%s\n' "hello world"`, the result is (properly) `printf '%s\n' 'hello world'`.

Comment: (Yes, `"$@"` is correct to call **within your function**, but the point is that the *output* of the function isn't safe to evaluate or otherwise invoke; as such, it doesn't unambiguously reflect the text of the command being run).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i gave in, used %q, but i still posted my POSIX compatible evaluatable alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156682/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-samuel-kirschner).

Answer (score 0):

Use `set -x` to enable command logging and `set +x` to turn it back off.

Answer (score 0):

First -- if your only need is logging, use `set -x` to enable the shell's built-in logging capabilities; it's the Right Tool For The Job.

---

To generate a shell-quoted string reflecting the text of a command, you can either use the bash and ksh extension `printf '%q'`, or rely on a 3rd-party scripting language providing such functionality. Consider, then:

```
# needs Python, supported on all POSIX-y shells, output works on all POSIX shells
print_quoted() {
  python -c 'import sys, pipes; print(" ".join(pipes.quote(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]))' "$@"
}
```

...or...

```
# More efficient; needs bash or ksh; unusual inputs may result in outputs that only work
# on the same shell (ie. $''-quoted strings).
print_quoted() {
  printf '%q ' "$@"
  printf '\n'
}
```

Once you've chosen one of the above, it's easy to incorporate elsewhere:

```
print_and_execute() {
  print_quoted "$@" >&2  # actually print
  "$@"                   # execute
}
```